# how to create multiple row selection

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../defaults/defaults.dart';
import 'items/additem.dart';
        
class SearchItem extends StatefulWidget {
    const SearchItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);       
    @override
    State<SearchItem> createState() => _SearchItemState();
}

class _SearchItemState extends State<SearchItem> {
    // my variables
    int? selectedIndex;
    List<DataRow> itemListData = <DataRow>[];

    List<DataCell> _createCellsForElement(DocumentSnapshot document) 
     {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()
        as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text(data['itemid'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['isbn'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['itemName'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['productId'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['category'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['costPrice'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['quantity'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['sellingPrice'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['amount'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['promoEndDt'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(IconButton(onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete))),
        ];
    }

//<-- creating list of column*

     final columns = [
            'ID',
            'UPC/EAN/ISBN',
            'ITEM NAME',
            'CATEGORY',
            'SUPPLIER',
            'COST PRICE',
            'QUANTITY',
            'SELLING PRICE',
            'AMOUNT',
            'EXPIRY DATE',
            'DELETE'
        ];
        //<-- creating list of column map it into string type
        List<DataColumn> getcolumns(List<String> columns) => columns
        .map((String column) => DataColumn(
            label: Text(column, style:  Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal))).toList();
        bool checked = false;
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                    Text('Item List',style: Defaults.drawerTextStyleHeadBlack),
```

### ****//Here is the section where am having the problem // i have 8 items in my firebase data and // when i click on a row it make a duplicate of all rows //and select the the last 8 row //how can i get rid of it***

```
     Container(
         margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 20, 0),
         child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
         stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('ItemsCollection')
         .snapshots(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
             List<DataRow> itemListData = <DataRow>[];
             if (snapshot.hasError) {
                 return Text('Something went Wrong!');
             } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                 var index = 0;
                 var itemsnapshot = snapshot.data!;
                 for (var items in itemsnapshot.docs) {
                     itemListData.add(DataRow(
                         cells: _createCellsForElement(items),
                         selected: checked,
                         onSelectChanged: (bool? isSelected) {
                             setState(() {
                                 checked = isSelected!;
                             });
                         }));
                             index++;
                     }
                 } else {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                   }
```

*// creating a datatable wrapping it with single child scroll view*

```
                      return SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                          child: InteractiveViewer(
                          alignPanAxis: true,
                          child: DataTable(
                          columnSpacing: 20,
                          sortAscending: true,
                          columns: getcolumns(columns),
                          rows: itemListData,
                                         ),
                                   ),
                              );
                          },),
                      ),
                 ],
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `itemListData` is declared twice. One right below the class `_SearchItemState` and another in the `builder` function. Can you please remove the `itemListData` right below the class declaration and see what happens?

Comment: yes i have omitted one of it

Comment: Does it show any kind of error after removing it?

Comment: no error but it still  does the same thing selecting 8 items and creating a list of 8 rows again unselected

Comment: am still working on your suggestion i will let you know on any issue i come across with thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to hold the selected item, It can be list of index or item based on scenario. Then compare the render item is contain on selectedList or not.

Using list of index for selection will be

```dart
// on state class 
List<int> selectedIndex  =  [] ;
```

While render item

```dart
  selected: selectedIndex.contains(index),
```

to toggle selection

```dart
if (selectedIndex.contains(tappedIndex)) {
  selectedIndex.remove(tappedIndex);
} else {
  selectedIndex.add(tappedIndex);
}
```

Comment: need more briefing on tappedIndex  and please where am i to place the if statement

Comment: You can store `items`, it would be easier if you could provide simplified widget